# What is an ideal domain for FFT?

Tags: signal-processing, fft

I am using the Jtransforms library which seems to be wicked fast for my purpose.

At this point I think I have a pretty good handle on how FFT works so now I am wondering if there is any form of a standard domain which is used for audio visualizations like spectograms?

Thanks to android's native FFT in 2.3 I had been using bytes as the range although I am still unclear as to whether it is signed or not. (I know java doesn't have unsigned bytes, but Google implemented these functions natively and the waveform is PCM 8bit unsigned)

However I am adapting my app to work with mic audio and 2.1 phones. At this point having the input domain being in the range of bytes whether it is [-128, 127] or [0, 255] no longer seems quite optimal.

I would like the range of my FFT function to be [0,1] so that I can scale it easily.

So should I use a domain of [-1, 1] or [0, 1]?

Comment: I think you should remove the java and android tags, since this question is not specific to either. Also, you can ask questions of this sort on http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Will do, and thanks for the link, I had no idea they existed!

Comment: Check out DCT (wiki link in my answer), it limits the range like you wanted, however, it has more assumptions on the input domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, the input domain does not matter.  At most, it causes an offset and a change in scaling on your original data, which will be turned into an offset on bin #0 and an overall change in scaling on your frequency-domain results, respectively.

As to limiting your FFT output to [0,1]; that's essentially impossible.  In general, the FFT output will be complex, there's no way to manipulate your input data so that the output is restricted to positive real numbers.

Comment: Would I use bin #0 to rescale the other bins? If say I were using unsigned PCM at one point and then signed PCM later?

Comment: @Evan: The bins are all independent, you don't want to use one to scale the others.

Comment: Good to know.

Additionally my understanding was that you would simply find the magnitude of the complex and real data and scale it by 1/N where N is your input size.

Comment: @Evan: It's not necessary to do that.  That's just one possible normalisation approach.

Comment: Could you explain why not? Page 11 of this document: www.lomont.org/Software/Misc/FFT/SimpleFFT.pdf
Says that the output is scaled by a factor of N and everywhere I have read indicates to get the magnitude of your FFT you take the sqrt[real^2 + imaginary^2]

Comment: To add further, what would you recommend as a normalization approach for audio visualization?

Comment: @Evan: There is no universal definition of the FFT; scaling the forward FFT by 1/N is just one particular convention.  See e.g. the discussion of scaling at e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition for more details.

Comment: Thank you for that link! I noticed that I had been finding the amplitude backwards anyways.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [DCT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform) instead of [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fft) your output range will be real. (Read about the difference and decide if DCT is suitable for your application.)

FFT implementations for real numbers (as input domain) use half the samples for the output range (since there are only even results when the input is real), therefore the fact you have both real and imaginary parts for each sample doesn't effect the size of the result (vs the size of the source) much (output size is ceil(n/2)*2).